# find special character (ASCII 249) and rename files, folders and subfolders in a directory

Tags: find, rename

I'm looking for a find and rename command to rename all files, folders and sub-folders in a directory containing ASCII-Code-249. For example: `Ga¨rten` should be `Gärten`. So rename all `a¨` to `ä`.

Comment: ASCII only has characters for code points 0 to 127. That `¨` is Unicode U+00A8, encoded as 0xa8 in iso8859-1 or windows-1252 for instance and 0xc2 0xa8 in UTF-8 and doesn't exist in ASCII. The closest ASCII character is `"` (double quote). In what charset are your file names encoded?

Comment: I checked my MacBook has utf-8 and my Synology NAS has also utf-8 where the files are located. On Synology I can't install rename. I ran the command via my MacBook on the network share and nothing happened. The strange thing is I can access the files via Windows. Via Mac I can't open them. The files are both displayed correctly e.g. "Gärten". But when I run them through BareGrep I see the ASCII sign. When I manually go to the "Gärten" and delete the "ä" it switches to "a".

Comment: @ Stephane: How can I find out which charset my files are encoded? And the sign in my files is defenetly ASCII-Code-249. Ich checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Your system should be using utf-8 (it is now the standard). ASCII is only code points 0 to 127. 128 to 255 were various incompatible extensions iso8859-x. Where x is an integer. Unicode combines all of the characters and more. utf-8 is a unicode encoding that is fully backward compatible with ASCII (but not the extensions). And text written for an extension of ascii can be converted (if you know the encoding).

If it is displaying properly in a utf-8 terminal, then it is utf-8.
Therefore install `rename`

```
apt install rename #to install on any debian based distro
```

then

```
rename -n 's/a¨/ä/g' *
```

If it shows the correct results, then remove the `-n` to get it to do it for real.